# oracle 11g installation on linux eror: ./runInstaller

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While installing oracle `11g` there occurred an error when ./runInstaller entered. What may be the solution?

The error is shown below:

```
./runInstaller: line 92: 4906 Segmentation fault $CMDDIR/install/.oui
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `MOS`. You should always mention the exact `database version` and `OS` details.

I cannot share the details from `MOS` directly, so here are the references :

[Doc ID 435687.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=540052436431918&id=435687.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=n8iqn70xp_4#SYMPTOM)

Please note that it applies to :

```
Oracle Server - Enterprise Edition - Version: 10.2.0.1
Linux x86-64
```

Comment: [root@TomcatServer database]$ hostname
TomcatServer
[root@TomcatServer database]$ xhost +                               ( while giving this the result  is "unable o open the display... Could anyone please suggest a soluion for this??)

Comment: If you are login to a virtual machine, then you need to set the display too. `export DISPLAY=:1.0`

Comment: DISPLAY=<machine-name>:0.0; export DISPLAY  i added this too after that only ./runInstaller entered.. at that time              ./runInstaller: line 92: 4906 Segmentation fault $CMDDIR/install/.oui this particular error occurs..